# iOS Updated App Version - New Leaderboards and Accomplishments

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

When I create a version update in iTunes Connect, the Game Center leaderboards and accomplishments are empty.

[image: game center version page]

Will the old leaderboards persist or do I have to create new leaderboards?

If not, can I use the old names for my new leaderboards so I don't have to change my application source code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The existing ones will persist. The view you are looking at there is just for new leader boards that you need to submit with your new app version.

Comment: Thanks!  So I get an additional 25 leaderboards?  Now 50!

Comment: I don't think there is an increase in the total number of leaderboards you can have.